# How do I reference a local media file in a Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have set up my media root, media url etc. so the file will show up when I call

http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/something/somewhere/my_pdf.pdf

Now I want to show the same file within a template (i.e. the PDF in an object or embed tag plus some other stuff. I pass the path to the file (i.e. everything after 'media' in the view context, something like:

```
def test_doc(request):`
    p = r'something/somewhere/my_pdf.pdf'`
    return render(request, 'documents/test.html', {'pdf':p})
```

So what do I have to put in my template? I tried

```
<object data="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ pdf }}">something</object>
```

and many many variations thereof. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the PDF file a static file?

Comment: No. Static files work fine.

Comment: try to add - `type="application/pdf"` in object tag

Answer (score 5):

I tested your approach and I believe I was able to reproduce your issue.

- PDF was displayed in browser from address: http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/media/myapp/my_pdf.pdf
- PDF not displayed when loaded into an object with `<object data="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ pdf }}"></object>` in template
- PDF not displayed when loaded into an object with `<object data="{% get_media_prefix %}{{ pdf }}">` in template

There are two problems occurring simultaneously.

1. Django's default project settings enable [clickjacking protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/clickjacking/) using X-Frame-Options. This does not prevent loading the media files with a direct request, but does so when you try to load media into an object. Firefox Inspector shows an error message: *The loading of “http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/media/myapp/my_pdf.pdf” in a frame is denied by “X-Frame-Options“ directive set to “DENY“.*

Django's documentation tells to use `@xframe_options_exempt` decorator for the view. It did not help in my tests. Disabling clickjacking protection by  commenting out 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware' in settings.py allowed me to display PDF in an object with `<object data="media/myapp/my_pdf.pdf">` in the template.

2. Both `{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ pdf }}` and `{% get_media_prefix %}{{ pdf }}` tags in the template lead to loading the PDF from the disk with path "/media/myapp/my_pdf.pdf". Note the extra "/" in the beginning. You can prevent this by defining `p = 'media/myapp/my_pdf.pdf'` in the view and using `<object data="{{ pdf }}">` in the template. Not very elegant, but works when clickjacking middleware is disabled.

Answer (score 4):

Since you have set up `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL`, you should use the [`{% get_media_prefix %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#get-media-prefix) template tag:

```
{% load static %}
<object data="{% get_media_prefix %}{{ pdf }}">something</object>
```

**EDIT**:

If you are running in development mode (`DEBUG = True`), you also need to change your `urls.py` to serve media files:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: That just resolves to /media/something/somewhere/my_pdf.pdf but it still doesn't display.

Comment: Did that. Didn't help.

Comment: Like I wrote in the post, it shows up. Only when I rty to reference it in the template it doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code it doesn't look like `MEDIA_URL` is defined in your views context.

```py
from django.conf import settings

def test_doc(request):`
    p = r'something/somewhere/my_pdf.pdf'`
    return render(request, 'documents/test.html', {'pdf':p, 'MEDIA_URL': settings.MEDIA_URL})
```

Comment: OK. Added that. But what do I have to write in the template? I'm using {{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ pdf }} which evaluates to '/media/something\somewhere\my_pdf.pdf'. But it doesn't work.

Comment: If you add `type="text/html"` to the object tag does it appear?

Answer (score 0):

To complete answer of drec4s that fixes Django side stuff, you will need to add a markup like this one on your template :

```
<embed type="application/pdf" src= "{% get_media_prefix %}{{ pdf }}" width= "500" height= "375">
```